# Pandas: delete cells if last six characters contain any integer below threshold

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe, filter

Please forgive me for the title; I had a hard time summarizing a complex question.

I have a pandas dataframe of values that looks like this:

```
    col1         col2            col3          col4       
10_Q999999   111_Q4987666    110_Q277778   111_Q999999
```

Let's say the threshold is 7. I need to take that dataframe and delete each cell where any of the digits after _Q fall below the threshold of 7. For cells where each digit >= 7, I only want to keep the portion of the string before "_Q".

The desired output would look like this:

```
  col1            col2            col3          col4       
   10                                           111
```

I'm trying to figure out some way to split each column by "_Q", convert the last piece to a list of integers, take the minimum and then compare the minimum with the threshold, finally deleting the list of integers, but I'm stuck in the middle of a disgustingly nested list comprehension:

```
[[[int(z) for z in y[-3:] if (z != '') and "Q" not in z ] for y in chunk[x].astype(str).str.split("_") if y != ''] for x in chunk[cols] if x != '']
```

**Solution:**

```
s=~chunk.apply(lambda x : 
x.str.split('_Q').str[1].str.contains('[0:6]', na=False))
        chunk = chunk.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('_Q').str[0])[s].fillna('')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `split` with `contains`

```
s=~df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('_Q').str[1].str.contains('1|2|3|4|5|6'))
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('_Q').str[0])[s].fillna('')
Out[549]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   10            111
```

Comment: @SummerEla sorry for the misunderstanding , check the update

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks so much!

Comment: I did need to add an argument to handle na's: na=False. This lady is greatly appreciative of your help :)

Comment: You can replace the `1|2|3|...` with `[0-6]`.

Comment: Making the switch from 1 | 2 | 3| etc to [0-x] that @COLDSPEED suggested did increase the speed. Since the threshold is a user input value, I would have had to do a '|".join to create the string each time, and instead this just uses string formatting to enter the threshold. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I dislike `apply`, so I outline an alternative involving `stack`, `str.split`, and `np.where` for (hopefully) better performance.

```
v = df.stack()
sp = v.str.split('_Q')
i, j = sp.str[0], sp.str[1]

v[:] = np.where(j.str.contains('[0-6]'), '', i)
v.unstack()

  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   10            111
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, I'm showing that this is a little bit slower than Wen's method. 

apply: 
real    0m1.289s
user    0m1.417s
sys     0m3.403s

stack: 
real    0m1.401s
user    0m1.550s
sys     0m3.524s

Comment: @SummerEla Ok, thanks. I think the problem is with stack, that's nearly as slow as apply. I hope they fix it; there's a large scope for improvement ;-)